# Multiple syntax for functions in objects (Typescript)

Tags: typescript

There are multiple syntaxes for embedding functions in javascript objects, and multiple syntaxes for type annotations. For the purposes of this question, I will refer to them as "type in key" (`in` - Car1, Car3) and "type outside key" (`out` - Car2, Car4) - please let me know if there is a better way to describe them.

Looking at the `.js` output, all I can deduce is:

- Typescript throws no errors for any combination of `in` and `out` between typing and variable assignment
- `this` context is preserved ***only*** when `in` syntax is used for ***both type and variable declaration***
- Therefore `in` syntax must be the "right way" of doing this (???)

What other differences are there, if any, between embedding functions in objects using the various syntax combinations below?

### `.ts` file:

```js
interface Car1 {
    brand: string;
    summary(string): string;
}
interface Car2 {
    brand: string;
    summary: (string) => string;
}
interface Car3 {
    brand: string;
    summary(string): string;
}
interface Car4 {
    brand: string;
    summary: (string) => string;
}

const myFirstCar: Car1 = {
    brand: "Tesla",
    summary(color: string): string {
        return `This car is a ${color} ${this.brand}`;
    },
};
const mySecondCar: Car2 = {
    brand: "Ferrari",
    summary: (color: string) => {
        return `This car is a ${color} ${this.brand}`;
    },
};
const myThirdCar: Car3 = {
    brand: "Porsche",
    summary: (color: string) => {
        return `This car is a ${color} ${this.brand}`;
    },
};
const myFourthCar: Car4 = {
    brand: "Ferrari",
    summary: (color: string) => {
        return `This car is a ${color} ${this.brand}`;
    },
};

const color = "red";

console.log(myFirstCar.summary);
console.log(myFirstCar.summary(color));
console.log(mySecondCar.summary);
console.log(mySecondCar.summary(color));
console.log(myThirdCar.summary);
console.log(myThirdCar.summary(color));
console.log(myFourthCar.summary);
console.log(myFourthCar.summary(color));
```

### compiled `.js` file:

```js
var _this = this;
var myFirstCar = {
    brand: "Tesla",
    summary: function (color) {
        return "This car is a " + color + " " + this.brand;
    }
};
var mySecondCar = {
    brand: "Ferrari",
    summary: function (color) {
        return "This car is a " + color + " " + _this.brand;
    }
};
var myThirdCar = {
    brand: "Porsche",
    summary: function (color) {
        return "This car is a " + color + " " + _this.brand;
    }
};
var myFourthCar = {
    brand: "Ferrari",
    summary: function (color) {
        return "This car is a " + color + " " + _this.brand;
    }
};
var color = "red";
console.log(myFirstCar.summary);
console.log(myFirstCar.summary(color));
console.log(mySecondCar.summary);
console.log(mySecondCar.summary(color));
console.log(myThirdCar.summary);
console.log(myThirdCar.summary(color));
console.log(myFourthCar.summary);
console.log(myFourthCar.summary(color));
```

### Console Output

```
[Function: summary]
This car is a red Tesla
[Function: summary]
This car is a red undefined
[Function: summary]
This car is a red undefined
[Function: summarizeCar]
```

Edit:

- clarification of different syntax types referred to
- "type inside key", `in`, refers to the syntax used `Car1` and `Car3`
- "type outside key",`out`, refers to the syntax used for `Car2` and `Car4`

Comment: I get multiple errors in the above due to missing parameter names. Please post your actual TypeScript code, with errors corrected.

Comment: Please show isolated, clearly-labelled examples of what you mean by the "in" syntax and the "out" syntax.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was also confused that the OP thought their labeling of "in" and "out" syntax was clear and didn't need any explanation. I'm guessing that "in" means all type information is to the right of the `:` and the "out" means that  some of the type information is to the left of the `:`

Comment: Edits:
- clarification of different syntax types referred to
- "type inside key", `in`, refers to the syntax used Car1 and Car3
- "type outside key", `out`, refers to the syntax used for Car2 and Car4

Comment: Your confusion has provided the help I needed - thanks! I was using the default `tsc --init` configurations and running `tsc cars.ts` to compile, which apparently compiles to `cars.js` without emitting any errors. I just discovered that simply running `tsc` will cause multiple errors to be emitted in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, what you seem to be asking about is the difference between *method syntax* and *property syntax initialized with an arrow function*.

Method syntax (in JavaScript):

```
const carA = {
    brand: "Tesla",
    summary() {
        return `This car is a ${this.brand}`;
    }
};
```

Property syntax initialized with an arrow function:

```
const carB = {
    brand: "Tesla",
    summary: () => {
        return `This car is a ${this.brand}`;
    }
};
```

For completeness, there's a third: Property syntax initialized with a traditional function:

```
const carC = {
    brand: "Tesla",
    summary: function() {
        return `This car is a ${this.brand}`;
    }
};
```

When you do `obj.fn()`, if the function is a method (`carA`) or a traditional function (`carC`), `this` will be set to `obj` for the function call. But if `fn` is an arrow function (`carB`), since arrow functions *close over* `this`, `this` is whatever it was in the context where the arrow function was created, which *for your specific example* isn't what you want. Which is why `carB` in the above doesn't show the brand:

```js
const carA = {
    brand: "Tesla",
    summary() {
        return `This car is a ${this.brand}`;
    }
};

const carB = {
    brand: "Tesla",
    summary: () => {
        return `This car is a ${this.brand}`;
    }
};

const carC = {
    brand: "Tesla",
    summary: function() {
        return `This car is a ${this.brand}`;
    }
};

console.log("carA:", carA.summary()); // "carA: This car is a Tesla"
console.log("carB:", carB.summary()); // "carB: This car is a undefined"
console.log("carC:", carC.summary()); // "carC: This car is a Tesla"
```

> Therefore in syntax must be the "right way" of doing this (???)

Neither is "right." It depends on what you want. If you want the function to close over the `this` binding where the function was created (as you often want to), use an arrow function (`carB`). If you want `this` to be set by the caller depending on how the function is called (which you often want to), use either method syntax (`carA`) or property initializer syntax with a traditional function (`carC`).

(FWIW: The distinctions between method syntax and property initializer syntax with a traditional function are: A) Method syntax is more concise, and B) Methods have a link to the object on which they were defined so that they have access to `super`, the prototype of that object. Traditional functions can't use `super`.)

Comment: I meant to explain the `interface`s, but forgot to. But [Juan did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63414089/157247).

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here:

**First**: the syntax for types. The two different syntaxes mean the exact same thing (Note that your syntax for `interface Car1 {summary(string): string;}` is missing the parameter name).

That is

```
interface A {
  fun(val: string): string;
}
```

Is the exact same thing as

```
interface A {
  fun: (val: string) => string;
}
```

**Second**: The reason for the different behavior is the arrow vs normal functions you are using.

When you use

```
const myThirdCar: Car3 = {
    brand: "Porsche",
    summary: (color: string) => {
        return `This car is a ${color} ${this.brand}`;
    },
};
```

You are creating an arrow function where its `this` is bound to the surrounding context, which is the `_this` that TypeScript creates and uses in those functions when compiling to versions that don't support arrow functions.

Note that in your example, those functions would be using the `this` from the top level context, which is `window` in a browser and `global` under NodeJs, so people avoid it whenever possible because it's likely to introduce bugs unless you really know what you're doing.

When you do

```
const myFirstCar: Car1 = {
    brand: "Tesla",
    summary(color: string): string {
        return `This car is a ${color} ${this.brand}`;
    },
};
```

You are creating a regular function, where the `this` is determined by how it's called. In this case, because it's being called with property access (`myFirstCar.summary(color)`), the this of that function is going to be the element to the left of the `.`, that is, `myFirstCar`

Therefore, there is no "correct" way of doing this. I particularly prefer the `interface A {method(val:string): string}` because it seems more natural but you should just be consistent.

Regarding the object initializer syntax, there's also no "correct" way, it depends on whether you want arrow vs regular function behavior.